# Hiding </br> Tags from custom post content in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created custom post types with forms for the user to edit the content.  Within the "edit content" form I would like to hide the 
 tags which are displaying.  I have inserted the following - however it doesn't seem to be working within the custom post type form:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

function wpse_wpautop_nobr( $content ) {
    return wpautop( $content, false );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_wpautop_nobr' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse_wpautop_nobr' );
```

**This is the table containing the custom post types where the 
 tags are appearing in the content:**

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-1' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-2' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-3' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-4' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-5' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-6' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-7' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-8' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-9' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><strong>[cred_field field='supplier-10' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Supplier Name']</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-6wtj">[cred_field field='items-column-1' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-6wtj">[cred_field field='items-column-2' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-6wtj">[cred_field field='items-column-3' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-6wtj">[cred_field field='items-column-4' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-6wtj">[cred_field field='items-column-5' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-6wtj">[cred_field field='items-column-6' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy">[cred_field field='items-column-7' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy">[cred_field field='items-column-8' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy">[cred_field field='items-column-9' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy">[cred_field field='items-column-10' post='charity' value='' urlparam='' ‘placeholder’='Items Needed']</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Link to Website](http://charity.run-time.co.za)

[Screenshot of br tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD0Ex.png)

Comment: Where are the br tags?

Comment: @orabis I have added a screenshot showing where these tags appear - as you need to be logged in to see it

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that what you need is to unescape your text content. An easy way to do that is as follows

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = yourPost;
var unescaped= div.innerText|| div.textContent;
```

Updated solution:
If you are OK to use JQuery, here is an easy way to strip the br tag. Simply, you will get the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) content of this html text as follows (test is your current string, and str is the output you are looking for):

```
var test= "Test <br> test";
var str = $("<span>"+test+"</span>").text();   //"Test  test"
```

Comment: I have inserted this into my functions.php - but the br tags are still visible :(

Comment: You used the "unescaped" value?

Comment: I'm not sure that I used this correctly. Please kindly confirm the steps to be used when adding this code, and implementing it?

Comment: It seems that the "edit" screen is somehow displaying html along with tags, whilst the front end displays correctly as rich text.  Any ideas of how to strip the <br> tags from showing in the form editor on the backend?

Comment: The solution has been updated with a suggestion on how to strip html tags, not only br. This will be a generic solution, unless you are only interested in stripping the br tag only. If the later is your case, let me know as you will only need to replace all br strings with an empty string.